# is it possible rotate an element with react-draggable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable

I have a component wrap in `<Draggable>` tag, but react-draggable uses transform to move elements, i want to move element to right or left and rotate it.

```
const [deltaPosition, setDeltaPosition] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});

const handleDrag = (e, ui) => {
    const { x, y } = deltaPosition;

    setDeltaPosition({
        x: x + ui.deltaX,
        y: y + ui.deltaY,
    });
};

<Draggable axis='x' onDrag={handleDrag}>
    <Card style={{ transform: `rotate(${deltaPosition.x}deg)` }}>
        ...
    </Card>
</Draggable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieve to rotate the element, i just had to wrap `<Draggable>` in other tag (eg. `<div>`) and add the transform style to it:

```
const [deltaPosition, setDeltaPosition] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
const [rotation, setRotation] = useState(0);

const handleDrag = (e, ui) => {
    const { x, y } = deltaPosition;

    setDeltaPosition({
        x: x + ui.deltaX,
        y: y + ui.deltaY,
    });

    setRotation(rotation + ui.deltaX / 20);
};

<div style={{transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)`}}>
    <Draggable axis='x' onDrag={handleDrag}>
        <Card>
            ...
        </Card>
    </Draggable>
</div>
```